# Openlayers export KML and turn off (name) labels

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers

I can export a KML using Openlayers just fine.  Issue: I was wondering if there was some JS to add to turn off labels when displaying in Google Earth?

Thanks!

Comment: Question: what do you do with the KML you export? Just curious since I find it so hard to pop a "save as" dialog in javascript

Comment: By the way, I don't if you're interested: I want to improve this project https://github.com/Sirtrack/GoogleEarth-for-OpenLayers perhaps by looking at way OpenLayer.Format.KML works. I'd like to export information such as styles and use it on our Google Earth pseudo-layer

Comment: I use server side to force a download.  As explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364090/openlayers-write-and-save-a-kml-based-on-your-map/9364398#9364398

Comment: It would be nice to figure out how to style it correctly so the name on the pins doesn't show in Google Earth from OL.

Comment: Have you looked at this answer? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12356/feature-geometry-attributes-to-kml

Comment: I'm actually customizing the format to add timestamp attributes when a  "when" attribute is present in a feature, that's useful for our GPS data. Anyway, I do download all on the client using some HTML5 functions and other tricks, I'll send you the link if you're interested

Comment: here: http://hackworthy.blogspot.co.nz/2012/05/savedownload-data-generated-in.html